# Windows Azure VMs: Connection Timeout to Remote MySQL Database

Tags: python, mysql, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I'm having a unique problem with Windows Azure that I don't see on other providers. I've been running connections from remote VMs to a MySQL database running on a DigitalOcean VM. I've successfully connected with AWS, Rackspace, Google, and all other providers, but for some reason, Microsoft Azure VMs don't seem to work.

VM OS: Ubuntu 14.04

I'm trying to connect using PyMySQL and SQLAlchemy.

**What I've Tried:**

1. The port is open and listening
2. The user definitely has permission to upload data into the DB (other remote connections with this user all work fine).
3. I have even tried "ufw disable" for the Firewall on the Windows Azure VM
4. I've set 3306 as an endpoint on the Azure VM

Despite all my attempts, the connection cannot be established. Is there something I'm missing on the setup?

Comment: Where's the host? Azure VM is the MySQL host? It's not clear if you are trying to connect from workstations to a MySQL in Azure VM or Azure VM is the client accessing a VM with MySQL outside Azure datacenter.

Comment: @BrunoFaria the MySQL host is located on DigitalOcean.

Answer (score 0):

As Azure VMs disable ICMP and we can use SSH tunnels to allow outside access to internal network resources. However I don’t have resource to create a DigitalOcean VM, but I have created 2 Azure VMs in 2 Cloud Services to try to reproduce the issue.

I installed mysql-server in VM.1 and mysql-client in VM.2.

Then I tried to connect MySQL server directly from VM.2, I got message “can’t connect to MySQL…”.

To work around this issue, I followed [this post](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/create-your-own-dedicated-mysql-server-for-your-azure-websites/), created a SSH tunnel in VM.1 which hosted the MySQL server:

- Open port 3306, so a remote client can connect to your MySQL Server. Run the following command to open TCP port 3306

  `iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT`

  Now let’s check if the port 3306 is open by running this command:

  `sudo netstat -anltp|grep :3306`
- Create a SSH tunnel for port 3307

  `sudo ssh -fNg -L 3307:127.0.0.1:3306 azurevmuser@servername`
- Create an endpoint for the port 3307 in the dashboard of the VM in Azure management portal. For more details , See [how to add endpoint to you Virtual machine](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-set-up-endpoints/). Now your Database host name is `<vm_name>.cloudapp.net:3307`

Then connect MySQL server from VM.2 using command:

`# mysql -h <vm_1_name>.cloudapp.net -P 3307 -u user –pPassword`

and it would work fine. Feel free to let us know if we have any misunderstood on your issue.

Comment: Hey Gary, thanks for this information. It seems SSH Tunneling would be a good solution, should've thought of it before... I was just stuck on the idea that I might've missed something to enable a MySQL connection.